# Can a question be closed after a correct answer has been selected?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Can a question be closed after a correct answer has been selected? I was answering a question then I noticed a reply had a check mark, did I miss that or can it load after the page initially loads? Then when I went to submit my answer I was unable to because the question had been closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Questions can be closed at any time.  The Person asking the question decides whose answer to accept.  The community decides whether the question belongs on the site.

And yes - if an existing answer is accepted while you're writing a new one, the checkmark will appear on it immediately. That doesn't mean you can't or shouldn't still answer though, if you think you can provide a better answer than the one that's accepted.

Comment: Like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915663/jquery-ui-autocomplete-ui-item-is-undefined), for example...

Comment: "That doesn't mean you can't or shouldn't still answer though" is there anyway I could still add my answer since it was closed? I believe mine was better than the rest.

Comment: @Celeritas No, you can't submit a new answer after a question has been closed.